# Anaconda InstalI

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, spyder

I have downloaded Anaconda for Windows 8-64bit and Installed it but it's not opening.Infact when I click once on   the Anaconda Icon it just starts the Installation process all over again even though I have already done it that process before.I have tried uninstalling it and starting to download it again but still does not open.I want to open it so that I use Sypder and Jupiter.Why is my installation not sucessful,where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is OS and how do you install and download it?  And how do you try to start it?  These are the details that you have to share so that others can help you diagnose...

Comment: After succesful installation there should be a group of Anaconda things in the Start Menu, various command prompts, navigator and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Hello are you downloading the right architecture try downloading the 32 bit version and see if that works also try running it as admin